# Spring boot application packaged by maven plugin not working, works in IDE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, jar

I'm trying to build my 'perfectly working in IDE (IntelliJ)' spring boot application with spring-boot-maven-plugin, yet after sucessful build it does not start due to exceptions.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>pl.doseq</groupId>
    <artifactId>rwcentral</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>rwcentral</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>pl.doseq.rwcentral.RwcentralApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>rwcentral-backend</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

"java -jar rwcentral-backend.jar" output:

```
2021-03-22 19:57:12.051  INFO 1628 --- [           main] pl.doseq.rwcentral.RwcentralApplication  : Starting RwcentralApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 15.0.2 on DESKTOP-7F1GKEL with PID 1628 (C:\Users\Doseq\Desktop\rwcentral\target\rwcentral-backend.jar started by Doseq in C:\Users\Doseq\Desktop\rwcentral\target)
2021-03-22 19:57:12.054  INFO 1628 --- [           main] pl.doseq.rwcentral.RwcentralApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-03-22 19:57:13.223  INFO 1628 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-03-22 19:57:13.364  INFO 1628 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 130 ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-03-22 19:57:14.350  INFO 1628 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2021-03-22 19:57:14.366  INFO 1628 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-03-22 19:57:14.366  INFO 1628 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.43]
2021-03-22 19:57:14.450  INFO 1628 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-03-22 19:57:14.450  INFO 1628 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2331 ms
2021-03-22 19:57:14.534  INFO 1628 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-03-22 19:57:14.835  INFO 1628 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-03-22 19:57:14.842  INFO 1628 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb'
2021-03-22 19:57:15.070  INFO 1628 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-03-22 19:57:15.149  INFO 1628 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.28.Final
2021-03-22 19:57:15.322  INFO 1628 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-03-22 19:57:15.480  INFO 1628 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2021-03-22 19:57:16.201  INFO 1628 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-03-22 19:57:16.209  INFO 1628 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-03-22 19:57:16.648  WARN 1628 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-03-22 19:57:16.728  WARN 1628 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'actionController' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Doseq/Desktop/rwcentral/target/rwcentral-backend.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/pl/doseq/rwcentral/controller/ActionController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'actionService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Doseq/Desktop/rwcentral/target/rwcentral-backend.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/pl/doseq/rwcentral/service/ActionService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'shoperRequests' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Doseq/Desktop/rwcentral/target/rwcentral-backend.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/pl/doseq/rwcentral/service/consumer/shoper/ShoperRequests.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shoperService': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [pl.doseq.rwcentral.service.consumer.shoper.ShoperService] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@27f8302d]
2021-03-22 19:57:16.729  INFO 1628 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-03-22 19:57:16.732  INFO 1628 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-03-22 19:57:16.734  INFO 1628 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-03-22 19:57:16.736  INFO 1628 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-03-22 19:57:16.745  INFO 1628 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-03-22 19:57:16.779 ERROR 1628 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'actionController' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Doseq/Desktop/rwcentral/target/rwcentral-backend.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/pl/doseq/rwcentral/controller/ActionController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'actionService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Doseq/Desktop/rwcentral/target/rwcentral-backend.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/pl/doseq/rwcentral/service/ActionService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'shoperRequests' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Doseq/Desktop/rwcentral/target/rwcentral-backend.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/pl/doseq/rwcentral/service/consumer/shoper/ShoperRequests.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shoperService': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [pl.doseq.rwcentral.service.consumer.shoper.ShoperService] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@27f8302d]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:582) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
        at pl.doseq.rwcentral.RwcentralApplication.main(RwcentralApplication.java:31) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[rwcentral-backend.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107) ~[rwcentral-backend.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[rwcentral-backend.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[rwcentral-backend.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'actionService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Doseq/Desktop/rwcentral/target/rwcentral-backend.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/pl/doseq/rwcentral/service/ActionService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'shoperRequests' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Doseq/Desktop/rwcentral/target/rwcentral-backend.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/pl/doseq/rwcentral/service/consumer/shoper/ShoperRequests.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shoperService': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [pl.doseq.rwcentral.service.consumer.shoper.ShoperService] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@27f8302d]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'shoperRequests' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Doseq/Desktop/rwcentral/target/rwcentral-backend.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/pl/doseq/rwcentral/service/consumer/shoper/ShoperRequests.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shoperService': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [pl.doseq.rwcentral.service.consumer.shoper.ShoperService] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@27f8302d]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shoperService': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [pl.doseq.rwcentral.service.consumer.shoper.ShoperService] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@27f8302d]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1284) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1201) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [pl.doseq.rwcentral.service.consumer.shoper.ShoperService] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@27f8302d]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:267) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/configurationprocessor/json/JSONException
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3325) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2466) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONException
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:435) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[rwcentral-backend.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
        ... 75 common frames omitted
```

Everything works fine in IDE (IntelliJ), application compiles and runs smoothly without any problems. I've also suceeded with creating .jar file in IntelliJ Artifacts this one also works fine when ran with the same command as above. Since i would like to perform a continous integration and deployment i believe spring-boot-maven-plugin is the way. I've also tried to package application with maven-assembly but without any luck.

Comment: Do you inherit from spring-boot-parent?

Comment: @khmarbaise yes, i've added full pom.xml above

Comment: You are mixing different version of spring boot...

Answer (score 13):

Dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

uses/contains "org.json" dependency which methods i've utilized in my code. Spring-boot-configuration-processor dependency won't be included in jar file by spring-boot-maven-plugin. Including "org.json" dependency directly helped:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20210307</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Adding the above two dependencies solved my `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/configurationprocessor/json/JSONException` issue

Comment: Adding **org.json** dependency and replace org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json to org.json in import declarations works !